# Laravel Routing to non index method in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a route:

```
Route::get('/apply/submit', 'ApplyController@submit');
```

But I keep getting the standard Laravel error page.

My ApplyController:

```
class ApplyController extends BaseController {

    public function index() {
        return View::make('apply.apply', array('metaTitle' => 'China Aupair | Internships | Apply Online'));
    }

    public function submit() {
        return 'yay!';
    }

}
```

Which I don't understand because `Route::get('/apply', 'ApplyController@index');` works as it should.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know if it's causing the problem, but laravel routes may start without a slash. 'apply/submit'. Can you try that?

Comment: Use Route::post() if you are sending data to the submit method of the controller as stated in answer below. If not then explain your problem more clearly. Which standard error?.

Comment: @Sjors +1 It wasn't causing the problem but I have taken your advise as it looks a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the method you access this page. You probably try to send form (using POST  method) and you use `get` for the route. What you should do is change:

```
Route::get('/apply/submit', 'ApplyController@submit');
```

into

```
Route::post('/apply/submit', 'ApplyController@submit');
```

because you probably send a form and not run this route manually in browser using `http://localhost/yourproject/apply/submit`

Comment: You are right! If I navigate to it normally it works (didn't try that), but if I change the route to post it works. Thanks.